# How to remove action column from List view in salesforce

Tags: list-view

In my org i have created queues and list views for those queues. I was wondering if there is any way to remove first Action column from view. Users in my org have edit and delete permission on their profiles. so i want user to be able to edit or delete record only after accepting lead from queue and not directly at list view.

[image]

Is it even possible? Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Action Column can be removed from related list by editing page layout but not from Object's standard list view

Comment: Can we remove it from Custom List views that i have created?

Comment: You mean from Related list of any record from standard detail page? If yes, then you can

Comment: No, I meant if i create a custom list view can i remove 'Action' column from that view. (just asking because you mentioned standard list views)

Comment: Though you've created custom list view you cannot remove `Action` column.